# Error basic commands on multiple PHP Version used by Composer stacktrace

Tags: php, composer-php

I have multiple xampp running 2 different versions of PHP
I can also check version using these commands

1. C:\xampp8\php\php.exe C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar
2. created an alias = php8 -v and composer8 -v

PS : I just want to create a laravel project with multiple versions(PHP 5.3,7.4,8.1) for me to handle multiple projects with different versions. Do we have a cleaner way of doing this? Thanks

Now the problem is when i try to use the composer8 command even the basic one it's not working
Used command in image : "C:\xampp8\php\php.exe C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar -vvv about"

[Image error stacktrace on just composer about command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS8Ms.png)